# missing } and $ error in equation

Tags: missing

I got "Missing }and$ inserted" error and I don`t know where should I add one. Could anybody help, please?

```
 \begin{equation}\label{3eq}
 A{}^{+}=(a_{i1}\textsuperscript{+},a_{i2}\textsuperscript{+},...,a_{im}{}^{+}),{a_{ij}{\textsuperscript{+}}={$\max$_{1$\leq${i}$\leq${n}}{a_{ij}}}, j=1,2...,m.
  \end{equation}

updated
   \begin{equation}\label{3eq}
 A{}^{+}=(a_{i1}{}^{+},a_{i2}{}^{+},...,a_{im}{}^{+}),{a_{ij}{}^{+}}={\max_{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}{a_{ij}}}, j=1,2...,m.
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}\label{4eq}
  A^{-}={(a_{i1}{}^{-},a_{i2}{}^{-},...,a_{im}{}^{-})},{a_{ij}{}^{-}}={\max_{1\leq{i}\leq{n}}{a_{ij}}}, j=1,2...,m.
  \end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: please provide an example that can be run to show the problem. (why are you using `\textsuperscript` in math mode?) and also remove all the `$` you are already in math mode from `equation`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle,I repost the edited codes.I used $ because of the "missing $ error"

Comment: It would be good if you post one question with all equations which does not compile,  instead of editing and changing the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the second equation where you write `a{_{ij}` instead of `{a_{ij}` since a subscript (and a superscript) needs to be attached to something and can't be the first item in a group.

There are a number of other issues here. I'm not sure what you're doing with some of those outer braces in your equations and it's also not clear why you're using `\textsuperscript{+}` instead of `^{+`. If it's to get the plus after the subscript, you could write, e.g.,

```
a_{ij}{}^{+}
```

**Update** Also, I see, for some reason that you have `$`s inside your math mode. Those don't belong there, along with the enclosing braces.

Comment: ,Thanks for your comment, I edited the codes as you said, but I got the same error. I post the edited codes and a picture of what I want to type.

Comment: @baran see the update to the answer

Comment: @baran if you take the equations as in your question and delete every `$` it runs without error, although you should also remove many of the `{}`

Answer (score 1):

- I see that you've replaced all instances of `\textsuperscript{.}` with `{}^{.}` in the meantime. I'd suggest you get rid of the `{}` particles too. Do also tame the impulse to encase things more or less at random in curly braces.
- The expressions for `\min{...}` and `\max{...}` are much too complicated and contain syntax errors. See the code below for a rather simpler and more streamlined alternative.
- Do please replace all instances of `...` with `\dots` in order to get LaTeX to typeset proper typographic ellipses.
- Optionally, replace all instances of `\leq` with `\leqslant` in order to better replicate the material in the screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather' environment
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\leqslant' macro

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\mathbf{A}^{\!+}=(a_{i1}^{+},a_{i2}^{+},\dots,a_{im}^{+}),
 \quad {a_{ij}^{+}} = \max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}a_{ij}, 
 \quad j=1,2,\dots,m. \label{3eq} \\
\mathbf{A}^{\!-}=(a_{i1}^{-},a_{i2}^{-},\dots,a_{im}^{-}),
  \quad a_{ij}^{-} = \min_{1\leqslant i \leqslant n} a_{ij}, 
  \quad j=1,2,\dots,m. \label{4eq}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```